# Measurement and computation

Tags: geometry

A large wall in the shape of a parallelogram is to be painted at a cost of $\$ 20$ per litre. Each litre covers 5m$^2$. The wall has a base length of 30m and height of 10m. Find the cost of painting the wall?

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself?

Comment: Does the slant of the parallelogram make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** A parallelogram can be transformed into a rectangle, so the problem boils down to find the surface of a rectangle.

[image]

From http://rioranchomathcamp.com/PerimeterAreaVolume.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Area of wall = base × height
= 30×10=$300m^2$

$\because 5m^2$ is covered by 1 litre of paint

$\therefore 300m^2$ is covered by $\frac 15$ × 300 = 60 litres of paint.

$\therefore$ cost of painting = 60 × 20 = $\$ 1200$.

Comment: If you want to input dollar symbol as math formula, use `\$`.

Comment: @tetori thanks for the advice.